# Google Glass CardScrollView does not render while swiping

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

I'm attempting to create a GDK app that has a similar user interface as the sample Timer app in that it launches sub-activities in which to render CardScrollView instances that cycle through valid selections.

My problem is that once I am at the point where I cycle through the numbers, the CardScrollView stops rendering while the scrolling is in motion.  I can see the previous activity revealed and rendering until the activity containing the currently active cards stop scrolling.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the answer was that I'd foolishly applied the "MenuStyle" style that the Timer activity uses to all my sub-activities in the AndroidManifest.  This style specifies the following:

```
   <style name="MenuTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
   </style>
```

So indeed, given the null animation style and the transparent background, nothing would be displayed while the CardScrollView is in motion.